# JaxB last field returns null on unmarshall

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshall an xml file using JaxB. It gets all the values except the last part (value). The value can be a simple value or can be a list of values. I can get the value by excluding the translationObjectValue but this only applies to single values and not to the list of values. I wanted to support both value types. Below is the sample of my xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><translationObjectFile fileType="ASSETMETADATA">
  <translationObjectProperties>
    <property isMultiValue="false" nodePath="/content/dam/we-retail/fr/experiences/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska-1.jpg/jcr:content/metadata" propertyName="dc:description">Test92 - Desc</property>
    <property isMultiValue="false" nodePath="/content/dam/we-retail/fr/experiences/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska-1.jpg/jcr:content/metadata" propertyName="dc:rights">Sample Photography</property>
    <property isMultiValue="true" nodePath="/content/dam/we-retail/fr/experiences/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska-1.jpg/jcr:content/metadata" propertyName="dc:subject">
      <value order="0">alaska</value>
      <value order="1">bolivia</value>
      <value order="2">camping</value>
      <value order="3">condoriri</value>
    </property>
    <property isMultiValue="false" nodePath="/content/dam/we-retail/fr/experiences/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska/steelhead-and-spines-in-alaska-1.jpg/jcr:content/metadata" propertyName="dc:title">Test92 - Title</property>
  </translationObjectProperties>
</translationObjectFile>
```

Below are my getters/setters.

**TranslationObjectFile**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TranslationObjectFile {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String fileType;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String sourcePath;
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    private List<TranslationObjectProperty> translationObjectProperties;
```

**TranslationObjectProperty**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TranslationObjectProperty {
    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean isMultiValue;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String nodePath;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "propertyName")
    private String propertyNameValue;
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private List<TranslationObjectValue> subjectValue;
```

**TranslationObjectValue**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TranslationObjectValue {
    @XmlValue
    private String value;
```

Below is the code for unmarshalling the contents:

```
String inputStream = IOUtils.toString(xmlInputStream, "UTF-8"); 
final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TranslationObjectFile.class);
final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Object value = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(inputStream));
return (T) value;
```

Thank you in advance!